# jQuery replace space with non-breaking space between two specific words

Tags: jquery, replace, space

I've created the following script that searches the page for any instances of "Two words" and replaces the space with a non-breaking space:

```
var search = $('body').html();
search = search.replace(/Two words/g, function($1) {
    return ('<span class="no-break">' + $1 + '</span>');
});


$('body').html(search);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.no-break').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text($this.text().replace(/ /g, '\u00A0'));
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ggkpb/

However, when I place it onto my website, it's causing other jQuery and javascripts not to work.

Is there a better solution to mine? Something that won't upset the other scripts on my site.

Comment: It may not work on your site due to not being within `$(document).ready()`... jsFiddle does that automatically. Can you show an example of where this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$('body').html(search);
```

**recreates every element** in the body, **minus any event handlers** that may or may not have already been bound. So if you're going to use that technique you need to be one-hundred percent sure that you do it *before* you create any event handlers (except for handlers bound directly to the body or the document, I suppose).

Unrelated to the problem, note that you can make your code somewhat shorter because you can call `.html()` and `.text()` once each, passing a callback function that takes the current value and returns the new value (you don't need an `.each()` loop):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').html(function(i, oldHtml){
        return oldHtml.replace(/Two words/g, '<span class="no-break">Two words</span>');
    }); 
    $('.no-break').text(function(i,oldText) {
        return oldText.replace(/ /g, '\u00A0');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I only need it for navigation items so I don't need to search the entire body. And if I specify to the relative navigation classes, it allows the other scripts to work properly. Cheers!

Comment: Yep, if the element(s) you use the script on don't have children with event handlers or information stored via `.data()` it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of writing it.
Since you didn't post an error messages, then I'm sure if this fixes your problem.

```
$(function(){
    $('body').html(function(){
        return $(this).html().replace(/Two words/g, '<span class="no-break">Two words</span>');
    }); 
    $('.no-break').each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/ /g, '\u00A0'));
    });
});
```

Comment: If you pass a callback function to `.html()` you don't need to use `$(this).html()` within the function because jQuery passes the existing value as a parameter to your function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you separate your text from your javascripts. You could mark every block of text in your page using a Class

```
<div class="text">abcxyz...Two words...</div>
```

and then call

```
$('.text').each(function(){
      var search = $(this).html();
      search = search.replace(/Two words/g, function($1) {
            return ('<span class="no-break">' + $1 + '</span>');
      });
      $(this).html(search);
});
```